# how to push values in array and pass these values to Select tag

Tags: react-native

I want to push values in array and pass these values as options of select tag. I did following,

used plugin

```
import DropDown, {
  Select,
  Option,
  OptionList,
} from 'react-native-selectme';
```

assigned state as

```
this.state = {company:[]};
```

pushing in this array as

```
for(let i in data.companyRecord)
    company.push(data.companyRecord[i].companyname);
```

and assigning to select tag as

```
<Select
        width={250}
        ref="SELECT1"
        optionListRef={this._getOptionList.bind(this)}
        defaultValue="Select a Company ..."
        onSelect={this._company.bind(this)} asyncOptions={this.state.company}>
</Select>
```

But it is not working. It is showing that

```
undefined is not an object('evaluating children.length').
```

Please help me solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit the state like that.

```
const tempNames = [];    
for(let i in data.companyRecord)
    tempNames.push(data.companyRecord[i].companyname);
this.setState({ company: tempNames });
```

Now your state will have the correct values.

But there might still be some problem, because your error might suggest that this.state.company is undefined, however you correctly assigned this.state.company to an empty array before.

This could be due to this.state is undefined. Are you defining your selector in a own created function? And not in your class own render method? In that case you need to bind this to your method.

```
    renderSelector() {
        return (<Select
                width={250}
                ref="SELECT1"
                optionListRef={this._getOptionList.bind(this)}
                defaultValue="Select a Company ..."
                onSelect={this._company.bind(this)} asyncOptions={this.state.company}>
        </Select>);
    }
```

In your constructor you need to bind "this" to that method. Like this:

```
this.renderSelector = this.renderSelector.bind(this);
```

Comment: what should I write in my _getOptionList method

Comment: _getOptionList() {
    return this.refs['OPTIONLIST'];
  } this is what I wrote in my method. and

Comment: <OptionList ref="OPTIONLIST"/>
 this line I put after completing my select tag

Comment: Looking at the example here (is that the component you use?): https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-selectme. Yes you should put that in _getOptionList().

Comment: Looking at the documentation, it looks like you are using the component wrong. this.state.company should not be a list. It will be the selected value. Look through the example code again, and I think you will get it to work.